# how can i check object already exists in array

Tags: ios

what i am doing wrong

```
    [mutableArry addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:questionNumber]];
    NSLog(@"mutableArry=%@",mutableArry);
      NSLog(@" question not complete  count=%d",mutableArry.count);

    if (mutableArry.count==25) {
        NSLog(@"25 question complete%d",mutableArry.count);
    }

    NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",questionNumber];
    NSLog(@"str=%@",str);

  //  array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Nicola", @"Margherita", @"Luciano", @"Silvia", nil];
  if ([mutableArry containsObject:str]) {  //YES
    NSLog(@"Results");
  }
```

Comment: calling `NSString` str and `NSMutableArray` mutableArry does not look good in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your two lines:

```
[mutableArry addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:questionNumber]];
```

and

```
[mutableArry containsObject:str]
```

solution:

add the questionNumber also as NSString or lookup a number :) should bring more success ;)

```
NSMutableArray *ary = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:25]];
NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",25];

if([ary containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:25]])
    NSLog(@"ary contains object - number");

if([ary containsObject:str])
    NSLog(@"ary contains object - string");
else
    NSLog(@"ary doesn't contain object - string");
```

Log:
**ary contains object - number**
**ary doesn't contain object - string**

Answer (score 3):

You try to compare two different objects.
Your `str` object is not this one you put in array, so you can compare it.

So you can do this:

```
for(NSString *stringFromArr in mutableArry) {
   if([stringFromArr isEqualToString:str])
     NSLog(@"Results");
}
```

FYI: Your naming convention is not good...

Comment: you were 28 seconds faster than me at the identical answer, +1 to you

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([mutableArry containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:questionNumber]])
{
    NSLog(@"Results");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following instead of the last if statement.

```
for (NSString *object in mutableArry) {
    if (object isEqualToString:str) {
        NSLog(@"Match");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code by following. You are adding `NSNumber` instance and comparing `NSString`.

```
[mutableArry addObject:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:questionNumber]stringValue]];
NSLog(@"mutableArry=%@",mutableArry);
NSLog(@" question not complete  count=%d",mutableArry.count);

if (mutableArry.count==25) {
    NSLog(@"25 question complete%d",mutableArry.count);
}

NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",questionNumber];
NSLog(@"str=%@",str);

//  array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Nicola", @"Margherita",                                       @"Luciano", @"Silvia", nil];
if ([mutableArry containsObject:str]) // YES
{
    NSLog(@"Results");
}
```